# Having the column value based on if another column has value or not

Tags: pandas, dataframe, calculated-columns

I have a big customer data which records the number of times the customers visited my store in a year. It looks somewhat similar to the following

```
data = {'2012':[3, 1, 0, 1, 0], 
        '2013':[0, 2, 1, 1, 0],
        '2014':[1, 0, 0, 3, 1],
        '2015':[0, 0, 4, 0, 1],
        '2016':[2, 0, 1, 0, 0]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, index =['Cust1', 'Cust2', 'Cust3', 'Cust4', 'Cust5']) ; df

      2012  2013 2014 2015 2016
Cust1   3    0     1    0    2
Cust2   1    2     0    0    0
Cust3   0    1     0    4    1
Cust4   1    1     3    0    0
Cust5   0    0     1    1    0
```

I now want to add a fifth column to capture the number of years a customer has been with me, Thus the desired output would be as follows,

```
      2012  2013 2014 2015 2016 Csum
Cust1   3    0     1    0    2    3
Cust2   1    2     0    0    0    2
Cust3   0    1     0    4    1    3
Cust4   1    1     3    0    0    3
Cust5   0    0     1    1    0    2
```

I have tried several options with **apply**, **np.select**, **df.loc** etc. But nothing is providing me the desired result. Can you please help, many thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks a lot  Arkadiusz and Beny. Both solutions worked, didn't know its so simple!

Answer (score 2):

Try with `sum` for none 0 value

```
df['Csum'] = df.ne(0).sum(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use numpy:

```
df['Csum'] = np.count_nonzero(df, axis=1)
```